# Is it ok to make jokes on your answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

While answering a question, I usually do it as I would do it orally, which is using the simplest english I can and also trying to make it a bit fun, which is also just the way I speak. 
so the other day, when answering this question [electromagnetic...](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312107/) I said

> short answer : because Einstein said so.[..]

it was a way for me to emphasize that Einstein discovered the photoelectric effect.
But it turns out people didn't like my answer ( I got a couple of downvotes in the beginning )

So Fellow physicist I would like to know your opinion, is it ok to make jokes while answering questions?

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing inherently wrong with an occasional jokey aside.  (But don't go overboard --- [we hate fun here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).)

I think the comment on your post, which links to a definition of "argument from authority," is a good explanation of why that *particular* joke might have fallen flat.
People don't believe in the photoelectric effect because Einstein described it.
People tend to respect Einstein's ideas because he was the first person to describe the photoelectric effect correctly.  He was the first to explain several things correctly, but he certainly published his share of mistakes.
Understanding the difference between "I believe X because a smart person said so" and "I believe X because it fits observations" is a big part of the difference between people who misunderstand science and people who are successful in the sciences.

Answer (score 2):

Humor is (a) subjective and (b) a tool in the communications toolbox.

Voting depends on the judgement of the audience, so you need to use humor that the audience will judge as improving—or at least not harming—the answer, and the answer still needs to be a good one on its own merits.

And if you are getting comments that the humor is a problem then maybe you should take it out. Or you could wait to see how other users feel about the humor. Maybe someone will defend it too.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, no.....for the simple reason that you cannot go wrong  with a straight to the point answer, but there's always a very  good chance that  your sense of humour is not shared by everybody.

People want answers first and foremost: not always dry textbook-like answers, so think of interesting **relevant** illustrations to make your point,  but the odds are in your favour if you keep it straight.

There is a big, big difference between an entertaining answer and a "funny" one, you are in for a fall if you confuse the two.

I write for websites with large audiences now and again, its not the same as giving a live talk, where you can judge the mood of your audience, on PSE you can't, so I wouldn't.

Comment: Sir, I hope one day you encounter a situation which empirically contradicts your specific perspective on this issue in what you find to be the most humorous way possible. I resolutely disagree with the notion that there exists any scenario in which tactful humour is not okay